# Remove Banshee's sound menu support

Tags: banshee, indicator-sound

I am using 11.04 and Banshee is the default, but I rather stick with Rhythmbox. I want to remove banshee from the sound menu I went into the extensions tab and unchecked all the sound menu support and even the d-bus extension. I restarted the computer but Banshee is still in the sound menu. Is there any other way to get it off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out how to do it. In the extensions just only uncheck "Show Banshee in sound Menu" and that takes it off the sound menu.

Comment: > I found out how to do it. In the
> extensions just only uncheck "Show
> Banshee in sound Menu" and that takes
> it off the sound menu. This doesn´t work for me! Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

I quote [RSparker on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1596616):

> For the record, the entries of each
>   individual player on the sound menu
>   are stored in
>   `~/.cache/indicators/sound/familiar-players-db.keyfile`
>
> You can either delete it and all the
>   entries will be gone or selectively
>   edit each entry.

Comment: There is no sound in there it only says messages.

Comment: @DexterP17: Forgot that --my quote was from a 2010 post in Ubuntu Forums (sorry :/, maybe this changed in Natty). Try uninstalling Banshee Sound Menu extension (`sudo apt-get purge banshee-extension-soundmenu`.

Comment: I did that now and, but it's still there. I don't get why it is.

Comment: On the extentions tab make sure D-bus and sound menu are checked, then go back to the first tab in the preference and uncheck the sound menu option and that should take it off.

Comment: I don't have ~/.cache/indicators/sound/familiar-players-db.keyfile. In the ~/.cache/indicators/ folder I only have a messages folder and a seen-db.keyfile.OLD file. Is there another place that the familiar-players-db.keyfile would be located?